# Doctrine in Symfony 2: Listening for events from a particular Entity

Tags: php, events, doctrine, symfony

I have a Doctrine Entity (News) which I listen for the event `prePersist`. For that I use an event listener with the method `prePersist`.

My `services.yml` looks like this:

```
listener.entity.news:
    class: A\BBundle\Listeners\Entity\NewsListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

This is fine and everything works. But the documentation states that when a `persist()` is called, a `prePersist` event is spawned. Then as my config states `NewsListener` will catch it and execute some code. Inside the method where I catch the event I should check if the event comes from the `News` entity. Here is where I wonder, is it possible to tell Symfony to listen for prePersist events for a particular Entity and then pass it to my listener?

Currently (as I understand it), whenever doctrine spawns a `prePersist` event ALL listeners are notified. Isn't it better to say which listeners should listen which event spawners, even if that should be optional, rather than notifying all and letting them filter the ones they need?

I hope I asked my question correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it possible to tell Symfony to listen for prePersist events for a
>   particular Entity and then pass it to my listener?

No, it's not possible. Your listener will fire for every entity that is persisted. It's up to you to do an `instanceof` check in the event listener to ensure that your code only runs for a specific entity.

Comment: After a brief look at Doctrine documentation I found out that the events are spawned by Doctrine's own event dispatcher, so it's not really even up to symfony. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

This seems to be supported since Doctrine 2.4:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Comment: Doctrine ORM 2.4 can now be used with Symfony: `doctrine-bundle 1.2 -> doctrine/orm: >=2.2,<2.5-dev`

Answer (score 7):

This is possible since Doctrine 2.4 with the [Entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) feature.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"AppBundle\EntityListener\PostListener"})
 */
class Post
{
}

namespace AppBundle\EntityListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class PostListener
{
    public function preUpdate() {  }

    // or

    /** @ORM\PreUpdate */
    public function someOtherName() {  }
}
```

*What if I want to inject a dependency into the listener? Is this possible?*

Yes, this is possible starting with DoctrineBundle 1.3. You just need to register the entity listener as a service & tag it with the [doctrine.orm.entity_listener](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html) tag.

```
class PostListener
{
    public function __construct(SomeDependency $someDependency) {  }
}

services:
    app.post_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EntityListener\PostListener
        arguments: ["@app.some_dependency"]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

### Alternative method

Since DoctrineBundle 1.5 you can [register entity listeners via tags](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/pull/298), but this method is [yet to be documented](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5013).
This method doesn't require the listener to be mapped with the `EntityListeners` annotation.

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
}

namespace AppBundle\EntityListener;

class PostListener
{
    public function __construct(SomeDependency $someDependency) {  }

    public function preUpdate() {  }

    public function someOtherName() {  }
}

services:
    app.post_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EntityListener\PostListener
        arguments: ["@app.some_dependency"]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: AppBundle\Entity\Post, event: preUpdate }
            # or
            - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: AppBundle\Entity\Post, event: preUpdate, method: someOtherName }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you do in your listener, you could use lifecycle callbacks in the `News` entity, and implement the prePersist hook.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks

This way, the listener would be called only for the instance currently beeing persisted.

Comment: Well yes, but my `prePersist` needs access to services, and since I cannot inject such in an entity I have to move it to a listener (unfortunately). Thanks anyway!